# Comparing DateTimes: DateTime.Compare() versus relational operators

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

Here are two ways of comparing two DateTimes:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime then = new DateTime(2008, 8, 1);

// Method 1
if (DateTime.Compare(then, now) < 0)
    // ...

// Method 2
if (then < now)
    // ...
```

`.Compare` returns an integer (-1,0,1) indicating whether the first instance is earlier than, the same as, or later than the second instance.

My question is, why would I use `.Compare` when I can use relational operators (`<`,`<=`,`==`,`>=`,`>`) directly? It seems to me, using `.Compare`, I need to employ relational operators anyway (at least in the above example; alternatively I could create a switch statement examining cases -1, 0 and 1).

What situations would prefer or require usage of `DateTime.Compare()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Typically, the `.Compare` methods on types are used for Sorting, not for doing direct comparisons.

The [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface, when supported on a type, allows many framework classes to sort collections correctly (such as `List<T>.Sort`, for example).

That being said, if you want to be able to do a comparison within a generic class or method, restricting your generic arguments to types which implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` will allow you to use `.Compare()` for comparisons when a concrete type is unknown.

Answer (score 6):

When you're passing the object as an `IComparable`, the "relational" operators are not available. In this case, it can be handy.