# Dates Comparison in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date

I have two text boxes where i am populating them with calendar i,e I am getting dates into the textboxes in string format.

i,e `string startdate=txtstartdate.text;`

i,e `string enddate=txtenddate.text;`

now i need to compare these two dates. 
my requirement is: enddata should be greaterthan startdate.

Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: you can first convert the date string to date using DateTime.Parse(), then use DateTime.Compare() to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse them as dates and then compare them. Example:

```
DateTime sdate= DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text);
DateTime edate = DateTime.Parse(txtenddate.Text);

if(sdate>edate)
{
   Throw validation error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.TryParse` is the safest way because it doesn't throw exceptions like `DateTime.Parse`.  It returns `true/false` on the call so you can handle failures very simply.

```
string text1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string text2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4).ToString();

DateTime d1;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(text1, out d1)) Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse text1");

DateTime d2;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(text2, out d2)) Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse text2");

if(d1 > d2) Console.WriteLine("d1 \"{0}\" is greater than d2 \"{1}\"", d1, d2);
else Console.WriteLine("d1 \"{0}\" is not greater than d2 \"{1}\"", d1, d2);
```

Also, I noticed several answers using `Compare` and [I hardly ever use `.Compare`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625196/comparing-datetimes-datetime-compare-versus-relational-operators).

Comment: Too many people suggesting `Parse` with user imputed data. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim startDate As DateTime 
Dim endDate As DateTime 
Dim returnValue As Integer 

returnValue = DateTime.Compare(startDate, endDate)
```

If returnvalue is:
Less than zero -> startDate is earlier than endDate.
Zero -> startDate is the same as endDate.
Greater than zero -> startDate is later than endDate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Parse(enddate).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(startdate)) > 0) {
// enddate is later than startdate
}
```

That piece of code doesn't do any error checking. You may want to do error checking when parsing string into date.